# How to disable GUI when compiling the linux kernel?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

So I'm compiling the 6.0.3 kernel in Debian 11, and I've been given the task of getting the smallest kernel possible that boots and has Internet connection.

I find myself at a point where I've compiled the kernel 89 times in total, and my kernel has 599 static modules and 0 loadable modules.

I'm using the command `make nconfig` and I've searched high and low for the section to disable the GUI, but I can't find it. My OS boots still with a GUI, and I want to disable that because I'm sure I can remove a lot of modules that way and make my kernel even smaller.

Somebody knows which section of the menu has this option?

**EDIT:**

The task is finished and I've ended up with 533 static modules + 0 dynamic modules.
I literally can't remove any more modules, and the GUI is still working and there is no section in the menu to disable it.

You were all right, thanks!

Comment: Disabling GUI ??? Errr ??? The kernel is not responsible for launching/maintaining whatever GraphicalUI. Your init system **can** be but that is another story. You can indeed want a linux system without GUI. As far as the kernel is concerned you would surely save one module : The one associated to some in-kernel built graphic card driver. **1**. (one) (And possibly a couple of helpers too)

Comment: The reason you can't find a kernel option to "disable the GUI" is because the GUI isn't the kernel's job. I'll post a more complete answer in the morning if no one beats me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build a minimal kernel you should use `make tinyconfig` instead of `make nconfig`.

To disable the graphic interface, use:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

to revert back:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

But it doesn't make the kernel smaller.

Comment: I've used `make localmodconfig`, then `make nconfig` to reduce the kernel. I've tried `make tinyconfig` but I found it troublesome, since the kernel that you get is not functional for my hardware and you'd need to manually select additional modules, and that's impossible to do when you are just beginning to learn about the kernel like me

Answer (score 1):

You can't "disable the GUI" in the kernel config because the kernel does not manage the GUI in any way that's meaningful to your requirements.

The kernel handles device drivers, lowest-level network interaction, and memory and filesystem management.

The "GUI" you're talking about is handled (on most systems) by either Xorg or Wayland, and as a layer on top of that, by whatever window or desktop manager you're using.

If you do what GAD3R posted you'll disable the GUI, but it won't make your kernel any smaller, nor will re-enabling it make your kernel any bigger.

If you *really* want to squeeze as much out of the kernel as you can, you could disable all filesystem support aside from the initramfs, as well as all block devices, then modify the initramfs to include and run a dhcp client. *Technically* that will boot and have an internet connection. It just won't do anything useful with either.

Answer (score 0):

Is your system booting in UEFI style or classical BIOS style?

If you disable the GUI (with e.g. `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` for persistence, and `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target` to make it take immediate effect), you could then minimize the `make nconfig` options under `Device drivers` -> `Graphics support`:

If the option `Device drivers` -> `Firmware drivers` -> `Mark VGA/VBE/EFI FB as generic system framebuffer` (`SYSFB_SIMPLEFB`) is set, then you'll basically only need to pick the `Simple framebuffer driver` (`DRM_SIMPLEDRM`) under `Graphics support`.

If `SYSFB_SIMPLEFB` is unset, then you'll need to make sure `Device drivers` -> `Graphics support` -> `Frame buffer Devices` -> `Support for frame buffer devices` -> `EFI-based Framebuffer Support` (`FB_EFI`) is selected for UEFI.

For classical BIOS with `SYSFB_SIMPLEFB` unset, you could use `VESA VGA graphics support` (`FB_VESA`) in the same path, or just disable all the frame buffer devices and just make sure `Device Drivers` -> `Graphics support` -> `Console display driver support` -> `VGA text console` (`VGA_CONSOLE`) is set.

Going with the `VGA_CONSOLE` would allow you to also disable `Framebuffer console support` (`FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE`, in the same path as `VGA_CONSOLE`), but this is only possible with classical BIOS-style boot; using either `SYSFB_SIMPLEFB`, `FB_EFI` or `FB_VESA` will also require `FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE` to actually provide you with an usable console.

If you go with `VGA_CONSOLE`, you may also have to tweak your bootloader configuration to disable the `plymouth` boot splash functionality, to avoid errors: without the framebuffer drivers, there will be no way to display pretty pictures at system start-up, only text.

(If I've understood correctly, the BIOS "default display mode" is a VGA text mode that takes extended ASCII and per-character display attributes, while with UEFI, the "default display" is fundamentally a simple graphics-capable framebuffer with firmware-provided functions to easily render text on it.)

Answer (score -1):

In simple words, the Linux Kernel is the engine of an operating system that makes it even work. It has *almost nothing* to do with graphical user interfaces. GUIs are controlled by desktop environments which are NOT PART OF the kernel itself, such as XFCE, GNOME, KDE Plasma, etc. To make a kernel smaller, I would try disabling all unnecessary options and other device drivers that are not needed for the computer to boot. Hope that helps!